# SPD 2010 Custom Workflow - Unknown Error, documents disappearing

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have created a List Workflow in SharePoint Designer on Custom Document Library with 2 custom Content Types.  The workflow Checks-Out the current document, updates 3 text fields, Checks-In the document, then Moves the document using Submit File, through the Drop-Off Library.  It always runs the first time, and fails subsequent times.

Here is the workflow
[image]

This is one of many variations on the same that I have tried to get this workflow to run.  No matter what I change, I get the same result.

Here is what I get in the workflow history:
[image]

NOTE:  The document was NOT checked out when this workflow was initiated.

IN the ULS loges, I get different types of errors, but this is the common one I get each time:

File exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The file Trial Master File/AAF Test.pdf has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 23 Jun 2015 18:48:51 -0400. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81020037): The file Trial Master File/AAF Test.pdf has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 23 Jun 2015 18:48:51 -0400.
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int32 cbFile, Object punkFFM, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, Byte partitionToCheck, Int64 fragmentIdToCheck, String bstrCsvPartitionsToDelete, String bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.AddStreamOrBytesInternal(String urlOfFile, Stream file, PutFileOpt fileOpt, String createdBy, String modifiedBy, Int32 createdByID, Int32 modifiedByID, DateTime timeCreated, DateTime timeLastModified, Object varProperties, String checkInComment, Stream formatMetadata, String lockIdMatch, String etagToMatch, SPLockType lockType, String lockId, TimeSpan lockTimeout, Boolean validateRequiredFields, SPVirusCheckStatus& virusCheckStatus, String& virusCheckMessage, String& etagNew, Boolean& ignoredRequiredProps)

OUTCOME:  The outcome of running this workflow is the document is removed from the Document Library, but is nowhere to be found.  It certainly does not get routed to the proper location (another document library in the same site).

DEBUGGING NOTES

1. It runs fine the first time.  Every time I modify, Save and Publish, and then run the workflow, it runs as expected.
2. I created a similar workflow on a different library, and it works every time.  <<<  this is the most troublesome
3. I am the Administrator, and I have “verified” this is not a permissions issue.
4. The Content Organizer Rules are good.  They handle the Submit File fine the first time and with other documents in other libraries.
5. There are no other workflows on this list and no Event Receivers.

What would you try next to resolve this?

I have other variations of this workflow with similar errors.  Would it help to post them?

Answer (score 0):

To move file from one library to another try **Copy Item** instead of **Submit item using Move**

Here is what i have done to move document from one library to another.

[image]

Try this. It may solve your problem.